# Change UIToolbar Shadow Color For UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am styling a `UIToolbar` by changing the tint color of it and the tint color of its `UIBarButtonItem` subviews. I have it working except that I can't find how to change the the shadow color from a dark color to a light color for **the individual bar button items** (see example, bar button items look blurry):

[image: dark instead of light shadow]

How can I change the shadow on the `UIBarButtonItem` with style `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` to be white? I've uploaded a sample project [here](http://cl.ly/3r0N2V2B1h0E).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to add the buttons as `UIButton` contained in `UIBarButtonItem` and include any shadows in the PNG used for the `UIButton` image.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) there isn't a single mention of the word "shadow"
2. You use an image for the shadow, not a `UIColor`
3. *Some source code examples can be found @ [cocoaControls.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls)*

---

**For the [UIBarButtonItem appearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) only the 2 images and colors can be changed:**

**setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:**
Sets the background image for a given state and bar metrics.

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

---

**For the `UIToolBar`:**

1. For adding your own custom shadow [look at this StackOverflow
   post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595878/how-can-i-add-attached-drop-shadows-to-uinavigationbar-and-uitoolbar)
2. For using cocoa-predefined functions [look at UIToolBar Class
   Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**setShadowImage:forToolbarPosition:**
Sets the image to use for the toolbar shadow in a given position.

```
(void)setShadowImage:(UIImage *)shadowImage forToolbarPosition:(UIToolbarPosition)topOrBottom
```

**shadowImageForToolbarPosition:**
Returns the image to use for the toolbar shadow in a given position.

```
(UIImage *)shadowImageForToolbarPosition:(UIToolbarPosition)topOrBottom
```

---

**I don't know what else to say, there isn't a shadow method for the UIBarButtonItem.**
I hope this is self explanatory.

Comment: Doesn't this shadow apply to the UIToolbar? I want to change the shadow on the UIBarButtonItem (i.e. the view contained in the UIToolbar).

Comment: @KevinSylvestre Look at my new edit, you will have to create a special background image to work as your shadow, else check out cocoa controls.com to see some source code

Comment: Does this fix the shadow for the `UIBarButtonItem`? I can't figure out which part applies to it.